# Error in Python with for loop being out of range

Tags: python, loops, psychopy

I am writing a program in PsychoPy (a software meant for psychology experiments using Python) and keep getting a 'list index out of range' error. The problem appears on the line that says "if already_used_values[a] == value:". The only possible reason that I can see why this is happening would be because already_used_values starts off as an empty list; however, I thought that I solved that by saying return False if the list is empty. Below is the pertaining code for reference.

```
already_used_values = []#integers in order to sort sounds
sorted_sounds = []#note that these are not 'sorted', they are randomized each time
answer_key = []
def already_used(value):#returns true if value in array of sounds has been used
    if len(already_used_values) == 0:
        return False
    for a in already_used_values:
        if already_used_values[a] == value:
            return True
    return False
def pick_random_value(upLim):
    return random.randint(0,upLim-1)

def pick_sound(sound_list):#picks a sound randomly from list_of_sounds 
    new_value = pick_random_value(len(sound_list))
    while(already_used(new_value)):
        new_value = pick_random_value(len(sound_list))
    already_used_values.append(new_value)
    return sound_list[new_value]

def init_sorted_sounds():#appends random sound from list_of_sounds to sorted_sounds
    for i in list_of_sounds:
        sorted_sounds.append(pick_sound(list_of_sounds))
    answer_key = already_used_values
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please try to reduce the code to the [smallest possible example that still contains the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

This pair of lines:

```
for a in already_used_values:
    if already_used_values[a] == value:
```

is the root of the error you report.  When you say `for a in something`,  the variable `a` takes on each **value** of the elements of `something`, not each index.  Yet, in the next line, you're using `a` as an index.  So for example if  `already_used_values` is equal to `[ 5, 6 ]`,  on the first iteration `a` takes the value 5 and the subsequent line tries to examine `already_used_values[ 5 ]` which is clearly out of range of a 2-element list.

It's hard to tell the intention exactly, but it looks like your function `already_used`  can be reduced to the single boolean-valued expression `new_value in already_used_values`

So the line

```
while(already_used(new_value)):
```

becomes

```
while( new_value in already_used_values ):
```

and we get rid of the function.  But let's go one step further and recognize that, instead of the trial-and-error `while` loop you currently have, you can take a random pick of elements from a pool that *already* excludes used values before you perform the pick:

```
remaining_choices = [ x for x in sound_list if x not in already_used_values ]
new_value = random.choice( remaining_choices  )
already_used_values.append( new_value )
```

So that's got rid of the while loop.  But we can even optimize one step further as pointed out by [chthonicdaemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648033/chthonicdaemon) below.  It looks like, in the end, what you're aiming to do with all this code is simply to find a random reordering of a list.  This can be done in one or two lines:

```
sorted_sounds = list( list_of_sounds )  # make a copy of the original list of sounds
random.shuffle( sorted_sounds )  # randomly reorder the new list in place
```

Comment: You can go even further if your goal is simply to build a random permutation of the sounds: `sorted_sounds = range(len(list_of_sounds)); random.shuffle(sorted_sounds)`